# Beamer - setting image place in theme, specifying image in presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, packages, themes

I'm trying to create my own theme for beamer. Right now it looks like this:
[image]

It looks very similar in sections, too. To put an image I use tikz. For now it looks like this:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\gornagrafika{dna}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

While `\gornagrafika` requires:

```
\newcommand{\gornagrafika}[1]{\tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.center) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=.45\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}};}
```

Same in sections and subsections.

Is there any way to put similar code to `inner.sty`? To use something like

```
\titlepage{image}
```

or

```
\sectionpage{image}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the image name as arguments to the beamer templates for the title page and the section pages. In the following example, there are 3 possibilities to modify the image:

1. The default value is set in the definition, in this example `example-image`. These definition can easily go into a .sty file.
2. To change the images for the whole presentation, use

   ```
   \setbeamertemplate{title page}[mytheme][example-image-c]
   \setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytheme][example-image-c]
   ```

   in the preamble.
3. To change them during the presentation, just put `\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytheme][example-image-b]` where you want the change to happen.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}[1][example-image]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}
    \hspace*{-\Gm@lmargin}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=.45\paperheight]{#1}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytheme}[1][example-image]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \vspace*{-3cm}
    \hspace*{-\Gm@lmargin}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=.45\paperheight]{#1}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother  

\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}[plain,t]
        \sectionpage
    \end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mytheme][example-image-c]
\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytheme][example-image-c]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mytheme][example-image-a]

\begin{frame}[plain,t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Test}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}[mytheme][example-image-b]
\section{Bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]