# Changing title page in Beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I make my title page in beamer look like

[image]

with an vertically full width image and the blue bar in the bottom?

I don't know which functions to use to change this

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Women Matter: \\ Making the Breakthrough}
\subtitle{Presentation for Highways Agency/WTS}
\author{}
\date{18th of September 2012}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{vertical_image.jpg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a starting point: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335924/36296

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111067/36296